# Using SkiaSharp in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, skia, skiasharp

I'm researching the use of SkiaSharp for a future project, following the documentation currently available on GitHub:

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/drawing/introduction/

I'm developing on Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7. I tried using a Xamarin Android App project type but it requires a business licence for DllImportAttribute in SkiaSharp package.

I'm wondering if it's possible to select a C# Visual Studio project that will some how be able to display the SkiaSharp canvas, if so how would I do this?

Comment: How come the downvote, please explain so I can change my question

Comment: I was following the get started guide which didn't include the windows integration. Thanks for pointing to the samples :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The link on the comment is currently broken. Due to the fact that the folder "samples" might change path in the future again, whoever needs can start exploring from the https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp page.

More information about using SkiaSharp can be found on the [API documentation online](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/namespace/SkiaSharp/) and in this article about drawing with [skia sharp](https://blog.xamarin.com/drawing-with-skiasharp/?utm_medium=social&utm_campaign=blog&utm_source=googpleplus&utm_content=cross-platform-drawing-skiasharp)

For who needs a practical quick start on how to use it here some examples:

**Getting an SKCanvas**

```
using (var surface = SKSurface.Create (width: 640, height: 480, SKColorType.N_32, SKAlphaType.Premul)) {
SKCanvas myCanvas = surface.Canvas;

// Your drawing code goes here.
}
```

**Drawing Text**

```
// clear the canvas / fill with white
canvas.DrawColor (SKColors.White);

// set up drawing tools
using (var paint = new SKPaint ()) {
  paint.TextSize = 64.0f;
  paint.IsAntialias = true;
  paint.Color = new SKColor (0x42, 0x81, 0xA4);
  paint.IsStroke = false;

  // draw the text
  canvas.DrawText ("Skia", 0.0f, 64.0f, paint);
}
```

**Drawing Bitmaps**

```
Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead ("MyImage.png");

// clear the canvas / fill with white
canvas.DrawColor (SKColors.White);

// decode the bitmap from the stream
using (var stream = new SKManagedStream(fileStream))
using (var bitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(stream))
using (var paint = new SKPaint()) {
  canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap, SKRect.Create(Width, Height), paint);
}
```

**Drawing with Image Filters**

```
Stream fileStream = File.OpenRead ("MyImage.png"); // open a stream to an image file

// clear the canvas / fill with white
canvas.DrawColor (SKColors.White);

// decode the bitmap from the stream
using (var stream = new SKManagedStream(fileStream))
using (var bitmap = SKBitmap.Decode(stream))
using (var paint = new SKPaint()) {
  // create the image filter
  using (var filter = SKImageFilter.CreateBlur(5, 5)) {
    paint.ImageFilter = filter;

    // draw the bitmap through the filter
    canvas.DrawBitmap(bitmap, SKRect.Create(width, height), paint);
  }
}
```

Comment: could you tell me how can i return from this an image? I need to generate image with some text and then send it via stream to printer (all done on xamarin) i think i could you use this code but how to extract image (jpg or whatever and send as a stream?